# undefined method `find_each' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have code something like this.

```
@deliveries = User.find_uniq_deliveries(...)
.
.
.
(many conditions added using 'named_scope' )
@deliveries.sort do |a,b|
.
.
end
```

The main problem is this is fetching lots of results and giving Oracle  exception that more than 1000 elements are not allowed in 'in' statement. 
So I tried using find_each to fetch in batches

```
deliveries_list = [] 
@deliveries.find_each(:batch_size=999) do |delivery|
    deliveries_list.push(delivery)
end
@deliveries = deliveries_list
```

But this gives the exception

> undefined method `find_each' for []:Array

As you can see am quite new to rails ( coming from java) and rails totally don't make sense to me. What can I do to prevent Oracle SQL error but fetch data

EDIT :

```
  def find_uniq_deliveries(category,date,view)
    dels = []
    sent_deliveries.send("for_#{category}s").send("with_#{category}_status", view).for_date_range(date).collect(&:workflow_item).uniq.each do |m|
      dels << m.deliveries.first unless m.deliveries.empty?
    end
    dels.compact
  end
```

Comment: the full traceback should have listed the filename and line number from where the error came. Is your for_each inside find_uniq_deliveries ?? I doubt the presence of for_each in Ruby or Rails.

Comment: Thats a blunder from me , sorry  ! its find_each.

Comment: the error is in the line where sort is used.

Comment: Ok. It's not clear. Is the second code block the body of .find_uniq_deliveries method? Because @deliveries is coming out to be an array when actually it should be a Model or ActiveRecord::Relation or CollectionProxy object.

Comment: Can you make sure @deliveries is not empty?

Comment: I will check if it is empty . Updating the question with that uniq method description too.

Comment: if I am trying to get deliveries object , its calling each on it and again getting the exception

Comment: The error says all: you are calling `find_each` on `dels.compact`, which is an array, while [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) is a method defined for `ActiveRecord::Relation` instances

Comment: what is alternative for array,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of research for a week and learning about named_scopes by checking its source code. I understood what the problem was. The `@deliveries` is an object of class `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` . This class do not have find_each method. So I wrote a new named_scope for limit and offset in `Delivery` model file as follows :

```
named_scope :limit_and_offset, lambda { |lim,off| { :limit => lim, :offset=>off } }
```

After this , I called it in a loop passing offset and limit , for ex. first loop has offset=0, limit=999 , second loop has offset=999, limit=999 . I will add all the results into an emptry array. This loop continues till the result size is less than the limit value . This is working exactly the way I wanted , in batches.

```
set = 1
total_deliveries = []
set_limit=999
original_condition = @deliveries
loop do
    offset = (set-1) * set_limit
    temp_condition = original_condition.limit_and_offset(set_limit,offset)
    temp_deliveries = temp_condition.find(:all)
    total_deliveries+= temp_deliveries
    set += 1
    break if temp_deliveries.size < set_limit
end
@deliveries = total_deliveries.sort do |a, b|
```

Answer (score 4):

find_each must be called on an Active Record Query result.

You are returning an array from your find_uniq_deliveries so find_each is not supported.

You would need to rewrite your query to put the find_each call before your .collect(&:workflow_item).

See also the Active Record Query Interface for methods that are chainable:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

The .collect method will result in an array of values so you can't put find_each after that.

EDIT: Here is a quick example of how to refactor your code to use find_each

The basic recipe is:

1. Build up an Active Record Query prior to calling any non-query methods such as collect.
2. As part of that query, you will use find_each to iterate over your result set in a way that will dynamically fetch batches of results from the database.
3. Save the non Active Record calls such as collect for last.  You can return an array of results, but just know that you will not be able to call any other AR methods such as named scopes with this Array.

Here is an example find_uniq_deliveries that uses find_each and takes in a query:

```
 def find_uniq_deliveries(query,category,date,view)
   dels = []
   query.send("for_#{category}s").send("with_#{category}_status", view).for_date_range(date).find_each do |delivery|
     # do something with your delivery object and save result
     result = process_delivery(delivery)
     dels << result
   end
   dels.compact
 end
```

And you can call it with any Delivery query like so:

```
query = Delivery.some_named_scope.some_other_scope
find_uniq_deliveries(query,category,date,view)
```

Comment: This is an existing code so just to enable batching, not sure if I have to do all those changes and am a java developer, so stuck on this rails magic.

Comment: @Skeptor - find_each requires you to use the .each iterator to work through the results.  Your current approach is not compatible with this.  This will require a fairly big change in your technique to work with find_each.  Alternatively, you can just split your ids into groups of 1000 ids to work around your original issue :)

Comment: Thanks for your insight Tom Davies. Can you please elaborate on your alternative solution. I do not have access to directly modify the SQL right ?, unless I write a different code altogether.